# How can i append new string on the base router in NodeJS API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webapi

I have defined base route in my root - app.js file

```
const userTechnicalSkillController = require('./controllers/user-technical-skill');
app.use('/v1/api/user-technical-skill', userTechnicalSkillController);
```

in my userTechnicalSkillController file i have for example the other router added on the `base route` for example

```
router.get("", (req, res) => {
  userTechnicalSkill
    .getAll(req.query)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.json(err));
});


router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  userTechnicalSkill
    .getById(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.json(err));
});
```

so
with `router.get("",` the api call will be `http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user-technical-skill`
with `router.get("/:id",` `the api call will be`http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user-technical-skill/fea4b1a4-274d-4d58-8cea-d1bf211da4c8` etc...

i need to have now - route like

`http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user-technical-skill-unchosen`

Is there any way that i can append on my base route here -unchosen ?

I know that i can add a router.get('/unchosen') but then the route will be
`http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user-technical-skill/unchosen`

i need that to be departed with -

`http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user-technical-skill-unchosen`

*i tried*

```
router.get('-unchosen')
```

but id does not work

How can i do this ?

Comment: What do you use, express? Please mention it

Answer (score 0):

One solution it would be to have the 'unchoses' toute on a new controller.

One other solution is like so:

**app.js**

```
const userTechnicalSkillController = require('./controllers/user-technical-skill');
app.use('/v1/api', userTechnicalSkillController);
```

**userTechnicalSkillController.js**

`router.get("/user-technical-skill", (req, res) => {...})`

`router.get("/user-technical-skill/:id", (req, res) => {...})`

Your other route for the 'unchosen'
`router.get("/user-technical-skill-unchosen", (req, res) => {...})`